# How to scale Orion Context Broker on kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, fiware-orion

I have a test environment in kubernetes.
Where I have deployed 1 pod from Orion, 1 from IoTA-UL and another from IoTA-JSON, the Orion and IoTA databases with the indexes and disabled logs.

```
Indexes Orion 
 entities -> _id.id, _id.type, _id.servicePath

Indexes IoTA
 devices -> id, service, servicepath
 groups -> apikey, resource
```

I simulate 10,000 devices sending data every 30 seconds, via http(50%) and mqtt(50%). With that amount, the response of http requests begins to slow down, to the point that some begin to fail.

I have scaled orion to two pods but it starts to fail, it is configured as indicated in the guide.

Orion v.3.6.0 (Helm v.1.0.3)

| Envar | Value |
| --- | --- |
| ORION_PORT | 1026 |
| ORION_SOCKET_SERVICE | TRUE |
| ORION_SOCKET_SERVICE_PORT | 1027 |
| ORION_DISABLE_FILE_LOG | TRUE |
| ORION_CACHED_CONTEXT_DIRECTORY | /opt/orion/ldcontexts |
| ORION_MONGO_HOST | mongodb-headless |
| ORION_MONGO_DB | orion |
| ORION_MONGO_REPLICA_SET | rs0 |
| ORION_MULTI_SERVICE | TRUE |
| ORION_MONGO_AUTH_SOURCE | admin |
| ORION_DISABLE_METRICS | TRUE |
| ORION_STAT_COUNTERS | FALSE |
| ORION_STAT_SEM_WAIT | FALSE |
| ORION_STAT_TIMING | FALSE |
| ORION_STAT_NOTIF_QUEUE | FALSE |
| ORION_LOG_LEVEL | ERROR |
| ORION_TROE | FALSE |
| ORION_TROE_USER | user |
| ORION_TROE_PWD | password |
| ORION_TROE_HOST | postgres |
| ORION_TROE_PORT | 5432 |
| ORION_MAX_CONN | 10000 |
| ORION_MUTEX_POLICY | none |
| ORION_CONN_MEMORY | 128 |

IoTA-UL v.1.20.1
IoTA-JSON v.1.21.1

Similar envars

| Envar | Value IoTA UL | Value IoTA JSON |
| --- | --- | --- |
| IOTA_CB_HOST | orion | orion |
| IOTA_CB_PORT | 1026 | 1026 |
| IOTA_HTTP_PORT | 7896 | 7897 |
| IOTA_MONGO_DB | iotagent-ul | iotagent-json |
| IOTA_MONGO_HOST | mongodb-headless | mongodb-headless |
| IOTA_MONGO_PORT | 27017 | 27017 |
| IOTA_MONGO_REPLICASET | rs0 | rs0 |
| IOTA_MONGO_RETRIES | 50 | 50 |
| IOTA_MONGO_RETRY_TIME | 5 | 5 |
| IOTA_NORTH_PORT | 4041 | 4042 |
| IOTA_PROVIDER_URL | http://iot-agent-ul:4041 | http://iot-agent-json:4042 |
| IOTA_REGISTRY_TYPE | mongodb | mongodb |
| IOTA_MQTT_HOST | mosquitto | mosquitto |
| IOTA_MQTT_PORT | 1883 | 1883 |
| IOTA_MQTT_QOS | 1 | 1 |
| IOTA_AMQP_EXCHANGE | Direct | Direct |
| IOTA_AMQP_HOST | rabbitmq-headless | rabbitmq-headless |
| IOTA_AMQP_PASSWORD | amqp_client_password | amqp_client_password |
| IOTA_AMQP_PORT | 5672 | 5672 |
| IOTA_AMQP_RETRIES | 50 | 50 |
| IOTA_AMQP_RETRY_TIME | 10 | 10 |
| IOTA_AMQP_USERNAME | amqp_client | amqp_client |
| IOTA_LOG_LEVEL | ERROR | ERROR |

Am I missing something in the configuration?

Greetings, thanks

Comment: I don't find Orion 1.0.4 at https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/releases. Could you clarify which Orion version are you using by providing a link to it, please? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I got confused with the helm version. The version we are using of Orion is 3.6.0.

I edit it

Comment: ORION_TROE* env vars are not supported by Orion (see https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/doc/manuals/admin/cli.md#configuration-using-environment-variables). What are they?

Comment: I use orion helm chart 1.0.4 as a template (see https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/fiware/orion)

I think having extra environment variables shouldn't affect the problem. But if you think it's a problem, I can remove them.